# Does excavator badge only go towards edits of other users' posts?

Tags: support, badges, edit-badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)
>   [Should I have earned an “Excavator” badge for this?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115012/should-i-have-earned-an-excavator-badge-for-this)

I recently edited a question I had posted and had been inactive for 10 months, according to its sidebar.

Since then, I have not been awarded an excavator badge, which I thought was for editing a post over six months inactive.

So, does the badge only apply to editing other people's posts?

Comment: [no, they do not apply to your posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/67399#67399)