# Excavator Badge not in my profile

Tags: discussion, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How long does it take for badges to be awarded? How are they generated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1716/how-long-does-it-take-for-badges-to-be-awarded-how-are-they-generated)
>   [Should I have earned an “Excavator” badge for this?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115012/should-i-have-earned-an-excavator-badge-for-this)

I have edited the following question that has been inactive for more than 6 months. [Silverlight Animation without DispatcherTimer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882897/silverlight-animation-without-dispatchertimer)

However I do not see the Excavator badge in my profile. What is the reason for this?
https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=general&filter=all

Comment: The jobs that run to calculate who should get what badge isn't event based, it's run periodically. Wait a few hours, and you should see it. Also, it looks like you edited *your* post. You need to edit a post you didn't create.